# virtualbox bridged interface won't connect to internet

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to connect an ubuntu 12.04  to my local network + internet, i would like it to be directly reachable from the local network, NAT interface don't do it so i tried setting up a bridge (in the virtualbox GUI). But then i can access any other host on the LAN from the guest, but i can't access internet, the DHCP seems to work fine since my guest OS gets an IP in the correct range and with the correct mask. However i can't even ping the router which connect me to the internet (the same machine as the DHCP server).

here's my configuration:

- host machine: linux mint debian edition X86-64
- guests: win7 64 and ubuntu server 12.04 x86-64 (both have the same issue)
- router-gateway-dhcp: livebox from orange ISP
- host network interface: wifi usb dongle with chipset RTL8191SU (which works fine for my host)

I know the bridged mode isn't supported by all wireless adapter, but isn't it weird that i can access local network but not the internet?
maybe the problem comes from the gateway itself?  
any advice would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no problem in using VirtualBox in bridged mode on a laptop. I use it very often and on different platforms, yet it can be related to your network adapter.

Can you try to debug your network by using tcpdump (if familiar) or wireshark? I once had the problem that the mac address got rejected by the router. Can you check if the router is permissive for unauthorized mac addresses or anything alike?